# Как узнать высоту всплывающей клавиатуры на мобильных устройствах в браузере?

Tags: android, html, css, ios, mobile

Есть дизайн сайта, где текстовый инпут при активном состоянии находится строго над клавиатурой. Получается для этого мне нужно определять устройство и размер этой клавиатуры. Подскажите как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]